# ROS2 always starts wrong node rclpy

Tags: ros, ros2, rclpy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just started to program a new node of my project and tried to start it now and it always starts the wrong node. I have two nodes written in python, the first I wrote works fine, but the second one always starts the first instead of the second.
Here my package.xml, setup.py and setup.cfg of the new node (CartpoleView):

package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>cartpole_view</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>TODO: Package description</description>
  <maintainer email="info@luhbots.de">leonard</maintainer>
  <license>TODO: License declaration</license>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>

  <depend>rclpy</depend>
  <depend>custom_msgs</depend>

  <test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_python</build_type>
  </export>
</package>
```

setup.py of CartPole node:

```
from setuptools import setup
 
package_name = 'cartpole_view'
 
setup(
    name=package_name,
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=[],
    py_modules=[
        'scripts.main'
    ],
    install_requires=['setuptools'],
    zip_safe=True,
    author='user',
    author_email="user@todo.todo",
    maintainer='user',
    maintainer_email="user@todo.todo",
    keywords=['ROS', 'ROS2'],
    classifiers=[
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License',
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Topic :: Software Development',
    ],
    description='TODO: Package description.',
    license='Apache License, Version 2.0',
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'cartpole_view = scripts.main:main'
        ],
    },
)
```

and setup.cfg of CartPole node:

```
[develop]
script-dir=$base/lib/cartpole_view
[install]
install-scripts=$base/lib/cartpole_view
```

And now the same for my other node (which is always started instead of CartPole node):

package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>python_learner</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>TODO: Package description</description>
  <maintainer email="info@luhbots.de">leonard</maintainer>
  <license>TODO: License declaration</license>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>

  <depend>rclpy</depend>
  <depend>custom_msgs</depend>

  <test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_python</build_type>
  </export>
</package>
```

setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup
 
package_name = 'python_learner'
 
setup(
    name=package_name,
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=[],
    py_modules=[
        'scripts.main',
        'scripts.gym_interface',
        'scripts.test',
        'scripts.test_2',
        'scripts.double_deep_q_n'
    ],
    install_requires=['setuptools'],
    zip_safe=True,
    author='user',
    author_email="user@todo.todo",
    maintainer='user',
    maintainer_email="user@todo.todo",
    keywords=['ROS', 'ROS2'],
    classifiers=[
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License',
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Topic :: Software Development',
    ],
    description='TODO: Package description.',
    license='Apache License, Version 2.0',
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'python_learner = scripts.main:main'
        ],
    },
)
```

and setup.cfg:

```
[develop]
script-dir=$base/lib/python_learner
[install]
install-scripts=$base/lib/python_learner
```

If I build it using `colcon build` the cartpole node is being built, but if I start it with `ros2 run cartpole_view cartpole_view` it starts the gym_interface script, which is part of the `python_learner` node.... Anybody has any idea why this might be? I can't see anything wrong with the names etc. I tried deleting the install, build and log folders and rebuild the whole project, but still the same.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337370/ros2-always-starts-wrong-node-rclpy/) by [LeoE](https://answers.ros.org/users/38438/leoe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 196 on 2019-11-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like both packages `python_learner` and `cartepole_view` create and install a python package called `scripts`. Both create a `console_scripts` entry point importing `scripts.main`. I'd recommend renaming your python module from `scripts` to the package name.

A `console_scripts` entry point like `python_learner = scripts.main:main` means an executable called `python_learner` will be created that starts python,  imports something called `main` from `scripts.main`, and calls it. In other words, calling `python_learner` is like running the command: `python3 -c "from scripts.main import main ; main()"`. Since both packages are installing to `scripts.main`, I would assume both `python_learner` and `cartpole_view` would run the same code, whichever was installed last.

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2019-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LeoE](https://answers.ros.org/users/38438/leoe/) on 2019-11-11**:
I will try this out immediatley, but this means I'm not allowed to have the same folder (scripts is my python script folder) in both packages?! Thats really weird....

**Comment by [LeoE](https://answers.ros.org/users/38438/leoe/) on 2019-11-11**:
Do you know by any chance if this is wanted behaviour? Otherwise I would write a bug report. And thanks a lot, it works!

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2019-11-11**:
The arguments being passed to `setup.py` says `scripts` is more than a folder. The arguments to `py_modules` says "install `scripts/main.py` as `scripts.main` globally".  It might be helpful to read the first two examples (6.1 and 6.2) on this page: https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/examples.html

**Comment by [LeoE](https://answers.ros.org/users/38438/leoe/) on 2019-11-11**:
Thanks a lot!